# rts5139/rtsx_usb borked in 3.15+

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

Some time in 3.15, someone moved the rts5139 driver out of staging (I cannot find a changelog of this) and it got renamed to rtsx_usb. This, unfortunately, broke support for *at least* the RTS5139 card reader. I have found about zero other people on the internet having this problem (buried under all of the SVC repos that got indexed?), and was curious as to whether anyone here was having a similar problem and had fixed it.

Kernel versions tested to be experiencing the problem:

- 3.17.0-rc4

`lsmod | grep rts`:

```
rtsx_pci               37855  0 
rtsx_usb               17487  0 
mfd_core               12601  3 lpc_ich,rtsx_pci,rtsx_usb
usbcore               187093  9 btusb,snd_usb_audio,uvcvideo,rtsx_usb,snd_usbmidi_lib,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,xhci_hcd
```

`lsusb | grep -i rts`:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
```

Removing/reinserting the rtsx_usb module does nothing. Logs are silent when the reader is interacted with. Strange.

Comment: I have the same problem with kernel 3.16.6 and the RTS5129 card reader.

Comment: On OpenSUSE this problem is fixed with kernel 3.16.7

Comment: Same here on Linux Mint 17.2 under VirtualBox. It worked under Ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: As of 4.0 this appears to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: partitions on memory cards are now found under names such as `/dev/mmcblk0p1`. Maybe you have been waiting for `/dev/sdb1` to appear? Make sure `rtsx_usb` is loaded and try to mount `/dev/mmcblk0p1` (or a similar name).

If that's not a solution for you, you might want to `modprobe rtsx_usb` and post the related output of `dmesg`? In my case, it's

```
usbcore: registered new interface driver rtsx_usb
mmc0: new SDHC card at address e624
mmcblk0: mmc0:e624 SD04G 3.69 GiB 
mmcblk0: p1
```

Of course, you would make sure that the `rtsx_usb_`-related modules aren't already loaded when you `modprobe`.

*Just as an additional info:*

```
lsmod | grep rts

rtsx_usb_ms            16899  0 
memstick               13696  1 rtsx_usb_ms
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         25280  0 
rtsx_usb               17541  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
mmc_core              102374  2 mmc_block,rtsx_usb_sdmmc
mfd_core               12601  2 lpc_ich,rtsx_usb
usbcore               195340  7 usblp,uvcvideo,rtsx_usb,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Nope. Dead silent.

Answer (score 0):

As is pointed out in an answer to [RTS5129 Card Reader with Ubuntu 15.10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257033/rts5129-card-reader-with-ubuntu-15-10/272990), asymingt wrote a temporary fix this.

Direct link to the github repo: https://github.com/asymingt/rts5139